# Applying tests on @PostConstruct method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a method I want to test but it's marked with `@PostConstruct` annotation. This method at some point, throw an exception. Is it possible to test a method with such annotation using JUnit tests? Asking in general here rather than for a specific method

Comment: Yes - it's the same as any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test it as usual method, because `@PostConstruct` is Spring-specific annotation and isn't related to JUnit (this annotation will be proceed only if you use features from `spring-test` library like `SpringRunner`, `@SpringBootTest` and so on).